# How do you make a paginated list/catalog of thumbnails in java?

Tags: java, image, swing, pagination, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a panel with a paginated list of thumbnails and their filenames. The list also needs to be sortable by various metadata attached with the file. The thumbnails are 120px wide by 90px high. So far I have:

```
public void PhotoCatalog extends JPanel {
    private transient SortedList<PhotoMetadata> sortedThumbList;

    public void PhotoCatalog() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(sortedThumbList % 3, 3));
        Iterator<PhotoMetadata> iterator = sortedThumbList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Thumbnail thumbnail = new Thumbnail(iterator.next());
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.add(thumbnail, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            panel.add(new JLabel(iterator.next().getFilename(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            this.add(panel);
        }
    }

    public class Thumbnail extends JPanel {
        BufferedImage thumbnail = null;

        public void Thumbnail(PhotoMetadata data) {
            try {
                thumbnail = ImageIO.read(new File(data.getFilename()));
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}
        }
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2d.drawImage(thumbnail, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

I need to intergrate the actual list to be able to sort and paginate but I'm stumped where to begin and which list to use. The code I have so far displays a black image that isn't the right size.

1) How do I get the image to display in the catalog at the correct size?
2) How do I integrate a sortable list to add the thumbnails and their metadata to?

Thanks!

Comment: Those are both pretty broad questions, and while you have a shell for answering them, you haven't really taken many steps to attempt them. I would recommend breaking it down into more manageable chunks and tackling it.

Also: You're putting a JPanel into a JPanel into a JPanel. Are you sure you want this type of structure or maybe try a [different control to subclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ui/features/components.html)?

Comment: True... I guess my first question is what kind of list or table object is available thru Java that would allow me to accomplish paging, sorting, and displaying thumbnails? I'm looking to do a Windows Explorer thumbnail effect. JTable doesn't seem to quite get all the features I need.

Comment: What features do you require that a table does not supply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `drawImage()` can have a width and height that will scale the image. You can add each `thumbnail` to a [`JList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) in sorted order. A `JList` lets you change how the pictures get wrapped. Put the metadata in a tooltip for each `thumbnail`.

Edit:

> Can `JList` support paging?

Yes, add the list to a `JScrollPane`.

> And can it be dynamically updated?

Yes; you'll probably want to keep your `ListModel` sorted by overriding the add/insert methods of `DefaultListModel`.

Comment: Can JList support paging? And can it be dynamically updated? Users will be deleting and adding thumbnails.